# ***Exception: Prelude.head empty List. What is the base case?

Tags: haskell

I am writing a function of getting the product of 2 matrix.

```
transpose' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose' [[]] = []
transpose' m = (map head m) : transpose' (map tail m)

dotProduct :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int
dotProduct [] [] = 0
dotProduct (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x*y) + dotProduct xs ys

matrixProduct :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
matrixProduct [] _ = []
matrixProduct (x:xs) y = (map (dotProduct x) (transpose' y)):matrixProduct xs y
```

I always get something like `[[2,2, ***Exception: Prelude.head empty List`

Is it because I have wrong base case for the function?

I am not sure what that should be.

Comment: @Carsten Thanks for your suggestion.
I actually tried quite a few of the base case for example `matrixProduct [] [] = []` `matrixProduct [] _ = []` and it still has the the exception.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it helped me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the issues I found in your solution and this is what I would get:

```
transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose [] = repeat []
transpose (m:ms) = zipWith (:) m (transpose ms)

dotProduct :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int
dotProduct xs ys = sum $ zipWith (*) xs ys

matrixProduct :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
matrixProduct xs ys = [ [dotProduct x y | y <- transpose ys ] | x <- xs ]
```

as you can see this should be really close to the `row * col` definition of matrix-multiplication (the rows of a matrix in your representation are just the elements of the outer-list and the columns are the elements of the transposed matrix outer-list)

Aside from this I simplified your `dotProduct` a bit (but yours was fine) and 
fixed your `transpose'` - which by the way was the source of your error!

I think the basic idea was right but you got into trouble with the base case (which is `[]` not `[[]]`) and the way you should map the first row to the transposed rest - also note that you can use `repeat []` which will give you an infinite list of `[]` as `zipWith` will deal with it just fine - if you use `[]` instead your recursive case will break at `zipWith (:) m [] == []` and bubble up to just `[]`

---

my `transpose` is a bit different to yours and maybe to complicated - the problem with yours is that one or more list inside `m` could be empty which will cause `head` and `tail` to fail - so you have to guard this case:

```
transpose' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose' m
  | and (map (not . null) m) = (map head m) : transpose' (map tail m)
  | otherwise = []
```

- `map (not . null) m` will check each row if it is non-empty (`result: [bool]`)
- `and (map (not . null) m)` asserts that all rows are non-empty

Comment: Thanks!  I actually have never see these expresion.

Comment: The `$` and `<-` in the code, I didn't even know these syntax exist.

Comment: oh sorry - the `$` is just there to save some characters (it`s the same as `sum (zipWith (*) xs ys)` - you see: one `)` saved) - the other one are list comprehensions which are quite usefull - but can be expressed with the `do` notation - or in this case with a pair of `map`s - as well

Comment: So the exception I got is caused by both transpose' and matrixProduct since they does not check for empty list?

Comment: yes - I would suggest you play with the different versions and try it for yourself

Comment: Just realized tail recursion is required for transpose.  I am trying to figure it out