# Matrix Transpose with Tail Recursion Runs Forever

Tags: haskell

I am working on the transpose with matrix transpose but this wants to run forever.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
transpose'' :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
transpose'' [] acc = acc
transpose'' m acc = transpose'' (map tail m) (acc ++ [map head m])

transpose' m = transpose'' m []
```

---

Now I have a check for empty sublist, but is there a more elegant way to do it?

```
transpose' :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
check m
    |head m == [] = []
    |otherwise    = m
transpose'' [] acc = acc
transpose'' m acc = transpose'' (check (map tail m)) (acc ++ [map head m])
transpose' m = transpose'' m []
```

Comment: You appear to have added another question to this question. Please remove it from here and make another question with it in.

Comment: Two hints. You currently use tail recursion and an accumulator which you grow on the right: it would be cleaner to grow directly on the left of the result of a (non-tail-) recursive call. You currently use `map head` and `map tail` to take whole lists of things apart: it might be better to use `zipWith (:)` to put whole lists of things together.

Comment: @pigworker ... like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944035/exception-prelude-head-empty-list-what-is-the-base-case/32944488#32944488 ? ^^

Comment: @Carsten Aye. (Using the ZipList applicative structure) By the power of Control.Newtype, there's a three word solution...

Comment: @Carsten That is also my question but since I want it tail recursion so I open another question here.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it helped me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this clause:

```
transpose'' m acc = transpose'' (map tail m) (acc ++ [map head m])
```

We know if we reach this clause, then `m /= []`. Observe that `map tail m` has the same length as `m`, hence in particular *cannot* be `[]`, no matter what `m` is. Therefore the recursion cannot terminate.

To deal with this, you have a couple of options; one is to prune away empty sublists, and another is to use the first clause to check that all sublists are empty instead of checking that the list itself is empty. In either case, you will likely need to be more graceful about accepting lists with empty sublists; `tail` and `head` are bad functions to call on empty lists.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have my solution now but it is not elegant could you show me your way to do it?

Comment: @katharineKim That sounds like a great follow-up question! Feel free to ask, along with relevant details, e.g. the inelegant code and what you dislike about it, in a freshly opened question. I would suggest the code review stack exchange, except that it doesn't seem to be very well populated; perhaps asking here at StackOverflow would not be *too* off-topic, if you give a clear description of what you want to fix about your code.

Comment: that would be the 3rd question (I know of) about the same function ;)